# My Adsense ads is not showing on mobile devices on some pages only

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, yii

My Adsense ads are not showing on mobile devices on some pages only.I have used the huge amount of data on my website. One page show multiple records. google ads work fine for some records but some records getting the error.

Code:

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:block" data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxxxxx"
  data-ad-slot="xxxxx" data-ad-format="auto" data-full-width-responsive="false"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: No, I am not getting any error. But after some time I have refreshed the page then its worked fine. I have implemented my code with HTML code but I am getting the same issue.  You can check in following URL                                                                                           http://m.rentalhousingdeals.com/index-test.php?test=3